# Adding user with PowerShell in group in one forest from another

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have multiple domains in my forest and need to add user to group in domain xx.test.com from domain yy.test.com.

I read user with a command:

```
$ADUser = Get-ADUser -Server "DC1.yy.test.com" -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$UPN'"  -Properties *
```

it ok.

When i try to adding this user in another domain whit command

```
Add-ADGroupMember  -Identity $GroupName -Members $ADUser_UserPrincipalName -Server "DC2.xx.test.com:3269"
```

the answer is:

Add-ADGroupMember : Cannot find an object with identity: 'user@yy.test.com' under:
'DC=xx,DC=test,DC=com'

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming where you write :

```
-Members $ADUser_UserPrincipalName
```

you actually mean :

```
-Members $ADUser.UserPrincipalName
```

eg you're retrieving the UserPrincipalName property from the ADUser variable and trying to add that.

In which case I suspect that's your issue. You want to specify the entire object not just the UserPrincipalName since that's just the name, but passing the entire object will also tell the system where to find that user, eg within yy.test.com. So the correct command would be :

```
$ADUser = Get-ADUser -Server "DC1.yy.test.com" -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$UPN'"  -Properties * 
Add-ADGroupMember  -Identity $GroupName -Members $ADUser -Server "DC2.xx.test.com:3269"
```

That's why you're getting the error :

```
Cannot find an object with identity: 'user@yy.test.com' under: 'DC=xx,DC=test,DC=com'
```

because it's trying to find it within xx.test.com rather than knowing to look in yy.test.com

Edit to add, according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/add-adgroupmember?view=windowsserver2022-ps the expected value for Add-ADGroupMember is :

Distinguished name, GUID (objectGUID), Security identifier (objectSid)
or SAM account name (sAMAccountName)

not UserPrincipalName

Comment: I use $ADUser for this:  $ADUser_UserPrincipalName = $ADUser.UserPrincipalName and this not my trouble.
Then I try to add this user in user@yy.test.com it writed error

Comment: OK, but that's not what your question code said. Either way, I'd suggest the fix is to NOT specify UserPrincipalName, just pass the entire user object to Add-ADGroupMember. Filtering out that one property is pointless for anything other than pulling out and displaying information.